# Cannot run simply query, getting "missing right parenthesis" error

Tags: sql, oracle

What is wrong with this query?

```
select author_num from (henry_author where (contains(author_first,'Albert') > 0))
```

Keeps giving me an error that is is missing a right parenthesis?

Comment: why do you have a parenthesis before your table name?

Comment: Your SQL is malformed. Too many parentheses. You should have as few as possible. I'd say you'd only need 2 parentheses at most with what you have, and with a slightly different query you could achieve this with 0 parentheses.

Comment: Because before it was giving me a `ORA-20000: Oracle Text error: DRG-10599: column is not indexed` error. :/

Comment: Why is this question tagged as Java?

Comment: @azurefrog OP is likely using Java to run this query, ie. JDBC.

Comment: @azurefrog, I'm using JDBC to query in the SQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT author_num FROM henry_author WHERE author_first LIKE '%Albert%';
```

or, probably better to account for data inconsistencies:

```
SELECT author_num FROM henry_author WHERE UPPER(author_first) LIKE '%ALBERT%';
```

The `%` is a wildcard matching zero or more characters. So `%ALBERT%` means anything can be before or after 'ALBERT', which is effectively what your `contains()` function is doing.

`UPPER` is just a function which converts the string into upper case characters, which makes it easier to deal with potential data inconsistencies, ie. someone typed in 'albert' instead of 'Albert', etc.

Since you're using JDBC, you might want to structure your query to use `PreparedStatement` which will allow you to parameterize your query like so:

```
final String sqlSelectAuthorNum = "SELECT author_num FROM henry_author WHERE UPPER(author_first) LIKE ?";
final PreparedStatement psSelectAuthorNum = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelectAuthorNum);

// now execute your query someplace in your code.
psSelectAuthorNum.setString(1, "%" + authorName + "%");
final ResultSet rsAuthorNum = psSelectAuthorNum.executeQuery();
if (rsAuthorNum.isBeforeFirst()) {
    while (rsAuthorNum.next()) {
        int authorNumber = rsAuthorNum.getInt(1);
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: It means what is says - you have an invalid column name in your query. Either `author_num` or `author_first` does not exist in table `henry_author` or they are spelled wrong.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! :D